# Finding the indices of the array as numbers (i,j to ij)

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert indices 1,1 to 11; 1,6 to 16 etc,

It seems I am trying to go in reverse because I am only getting 11 and 61. In the code, find() simply finds the indices of the array as [1,1] and [1,6]

```
for i in range(2):
    indices=(find(items[i],arr))
    print(indices)
    count = 1
    result= 0;
    for j in indices:
         result+= count * j
         count *= 10
    decimal[i]=result
    print(decimal)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you format your code and show enough to reproduce the issue? Such as what is `coord` and `noktalar`?

Comment: I edited it, coord was indices, that had [1,1] and  [1,6] as elements. And noktalar was decimal result array, that its elements should be 11 and 16.

Comment: is it clear now?

Comment: Can't we use join method and convert the string into an integer or decimal

Answer (score 1):

Is it python3?
Try reversed() in for loop

```
for j in reversed(indices):
```

Answer (score 0):

The relevant part of your code that converts `(1, 6)` into `61` is:

```
count = 1
result = 0;
for j in indices:
     result += count * j
     count *= 10
```

The simplest way to reverse this is to change it to:

```
result = 0;
for j in indices:
     result = result * 10 + j
```

This gives the result you are looking for.
Initially `result` is `0`, so `0 * 10 + j` is equal to `j`. For the input `(1, 6)`, this is `1`, so `result` is set to `1`.
In the next iteration, `j` is `6`, so `result` is set to `1 * 10 + 6` which is `16`.